# DOM like parser for lua similar to perls PPI

Tags: lua

Im looking for a DOM parser for the lua language that works similar to the great PPI parser for perl.

Basically i have a lot of lua scripts bound to specific entities - i want to evaluate some specific function calls within these scripts to show some generic information about a script (generate a report for example).

E.g.

```
function func1()

....
  if(check(1,4)) 

  end
end
```

In this case, i want the dom parser to find the function call check with a number of arguments.

I dont want to use regexp or similar tools, a DOM parser would be the best.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do... Can you explain what this PPI parser in Perl does?

Comment: ppi is like a XML parser for perl - and i need something similar for lua - something that builds a DOM of a lua script and which i can traverse for function calls including node search and has some kind of callback mechanism (e.g. when the parser finds myFunc(...) call my report logic)

Answer (score 0):

[LuaInspect](https://github.com/davidm/lua-inspect) is what you want.

LuaInspect builds an AST (what you are calling a DOM) from Lua code, and can perform static analysis on it. It can generate an HTML report, and is also used to for code completion in some editors.

`command.lua` is LuaInspect's main file, which uses `ast.lua` to build the AST, etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but in the meantime i found ANTLR to be exactly what i want without any compromise, it can be used from pretty much any language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955707/using-antlr-to-parse-lua-if-statements-in-specific-functions